# Oracle select two (or more) adjacent rows having the same value for a given column

Tags: oracle

How do I do the following in Oracle:

I have a (simplified) table:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|  a  |  b  | ... |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  7  | ... |
|  2  |  5  | ... |
|  1  |  7  | ... |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Where `a` functions as a unique identifier for a person, and `b` is the field I am interested in matching across rows.  How do I construct a query that basically says "give me the person-ID's where the person has multiple `b` values (i.e., duplicates)"?

So far I have tried:

```
SELECT a FROM mytable GROUP BY a HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT b) > 1;
```

This feels close except it just gives me the user IDs where the user has **multiple unique** `b`'s, which I suspect is coming from the `DISTINCT` part, but I'm not sure how to change the query to achieve what I want.

Comment: `group by a,b having count(b) > 1` Yours would count `7,5,7` as 2 (one 7, one 5). this one one will count total Bs in any grouping, so you'll get 1,7 - > 2 and 1,5 -> 1

Comment: Thanks @MarcB, I'm trying it now to confirm it works.  Is it normal that the query is now taking an extra-long time to execute? (been executing for about 5m now...)

Comment: depends on how big the table is. for a few thousands/hundreds of thousands of records, 5m is ludicrously slow

Comment: It was running on ~10 minutes...there's 3.8 million records, though.  Any way to limit the query to, say, the first 50 results?

Comment: an index on `a` would help, no doubt. not sure about oracle syntax, but there should be likea  `select top 50` or `select ... limit 50` type thing available.

Comment: Thanks for your help @MarcB, would you like to put your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
group by a,b having count(b) > 1
```

Yours would count `7,5,7` as 2 (one `7`, one `5`). This one one will count total Bs in any grouping, so you'll get `1,7` - > `2` and `1,5` -> `1`

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/82279/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable ( a, b ) AS
SELECT LEVEL, LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2000
UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL *2, LEVEL * 2 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH data AS (
 SELECT a
 FROM mytable
 GROUP BY a
 HAVING COUNT(b) > COUNT( DISTINCT b )
 ORDER BY a
),
numbered AS (
 SELECT a,
 ROWNUM AS rn
 FROM data
)
SELECT a
FROM numbered
WHERE rn <= 20
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/82279/5/0)**:

```
|  A |
|----|
|  2 |
|  4 |
|  6 |
|  8 |
| 10 |
| 12 |
| 14 |
| 16 |
| 18 |
| 20 |
| 22 |
| 24 |
| 26 |
| 28 |
| 30 |
| 32 |
| 34 |
| 36 |
| 38 |
| 40 |
```